# Sharing variables between functions in a PHP class

Tags: php, class, properties

This can be a duplicate question, but ... I read several answers here and the info on php.net about class properties (variables) and how to declare them, but I fail to apply successfully this knowledge. More exactly, I can't pass a variable from a function to another within this class. My class was built for Wordpress and schematically looks as below. All functions runs in the same order as they are in the class. In the `getForm()` function a variable `$_POST['postid']` with a post ID is received and the post with this ID is taken. What I need is to pass the post ID to the `handleForm()` function and I fail this. Every time I try something I receive a message that my variable was not declared. How to do this correctly in this class?

```
class WPSE_Submit_From_Front {

    function __construct() {
        ...
        add_action( 'template_redirect',  array( $this, 'handleForm' ) );
    }

    function post_shortcode() {
        ...
    }

    function getForm() {

        if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && isset( $_POST['postid'] ) ) {
            $post_to_edit = array();
            $post_to_edit = get_post( $_POST['postid'] );
            // I want to use the $post_to_edit->ID or
            // the $_POST['postid'] in the handleForm() function
            // these two variables have the same post ID
        }

        ob_start();
        ?>

        <form method="post">
            ...
        </form>

        <?php
        return ob_get_clean();
    }

    function handleForm() {
        ...
    }

}

new WPSE_Submit_From_Front;
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok so inside the class you can declare private variable:

```
private $post_id;
```

Then inside your `constructor` you can do:

```
$this->post_id = $_POST['postid'];
```

Now in any of your class methods $post_id will be accessible as `$this->post_id`

In your case it would look like this:

```
class WPSE_Submit_From_Front {

    private $post_id;

    function __construct() {
        $this->post_id = $_POST['postid'];
    }

    function post_shortcode() {
        $somevar = $this->post_id;        
    }

    function getForm() {

        if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $this->post_id ) ) {
            $post_to_edit = array();
            $post_to_edit = get_post( $this->post_id );
            // ...
        }

        // ...
    }

    function handleForm() {
        do_something_new($this->post_id);
    }

}
```

Comment: I checked in every class function with an `echo 'Post ID is ' . $this->post_to_edit_id;` if the `$this->post_id` have the post ID as a value and everything is OK except the `handleForm()` function, here the `$this->post_id` returns nothing (or doesn't exists, I don't know). If you want, you can see the original code with the next link. There I solved my problem with two hidden input fields, but I don't like this. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/212165/25187

Comment: I checked every code line in this class, but I don't understand why the `$this->post_id` property is clean (has nothing as value) only in the `handleForm()` function. Maybe because this function is executed by this: `add_action( 'template_redirect',  array( $this, 'handleForm' ) );`?

Answer (score -2):

You can add whatever you need as a class property:

```
Class WPSE_Submit_From_Front {
     public $post_id;
     public function set_post_id()
     { 
          $this->post_id = $POST['id'];
     }
 }
```

Comment: _Class_ is uppercase. $POST is not a valid PHP array ($_POST is) and what if $POST['id'] is not set?

Comment: Congrats, you pointed out some typos, let me edit that right now